# Ruby File.size for directory returns 0

Tags: ruby, file

The documentation say:

> File.size(file_name) => integer
>   Returns the size of file_name.
>
> File.size?(file_name) => Integer or
>   nil   Returns nil if file_name doesn‘t
>   exist or has zero size, the size of
>   the file otherwise.

On practice (ruby 1.8.7 i386-mswin32):

```
File.size?('c:/dir')   
# => nill
File.size('c:/dir')
# => 0
```

The nil makes sence for me, but 0? I would expect an exception instead. Do anybody see reason for this?

Comment: Probably the reason you would expect an exception is because you're used to languages that throw way too many exceptions.

Comment: @jason: Surely that's filesystem dependent. Try: File.size('/lost+found'). Also try: File.size('/proc'). :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directories *are* files. Well, I suppose in some operating systems they aren't, but in all Unix-based ones they are.

Of course, in Unix systems, directories in "regular" file systems (i.e., ones that have real files, not `/proc` or the like) have non-zero size too.

```
File.size('/etc')
=> 12288
```

Comment: Yeah, but the "c:/dir" should have been a clue that he's not on Unix.

Comment: @JS Bangs: That's true, however, I thought that Ruby, being designed for Unix originally, has features coded in to ensure some Unix compatibility, such as not throwing an exception when File.size is called on a directory. :-P

Comment: @JS Bangs. Actually ruby interpreter knows the OS it is running on, but I think the developers saw no sence in doing things differently on different OS's.

Comment: It would be pretty schizophrenic to return the directory size on Unix and throw an exception on Windows. Finding out if the thing doesn't really have a size is the whole point of the `size?` variant.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are as a general rule slow, so whenever the issue is not critical, it's better to use return flags for efficiency reasons.  As long as the file/directory exists, I see no use for an exception, and in fact would find one annoying.  Like this, calculating total file size is simply adding them up with no error-handling required.